# Can minors traveling to Brazil on US passports lose Brazilian citizenship?

Tags: brazilian-citizens

I have dual Brazilian/U.S. citizenship. My kids have U.S. passports but I have not been able to get them Brazilian birth certificates and passports yet. I have two questions. Would the kids lose their potential Brazilian citizenship if: 
 1) they do not get Brazilian birth certificates/passports by the time they turn 18? or if 
 2) they enter Brazil for the first time on American passports?

Comment: I would be very surprised if entering Brazil with a US passport stripped a US citizen from their citizenship.